# SQL developer - Finding distinct phone numbers when 2 phone number columns exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the count (in SQL developer) how many unique phone numbers customer has.
Customer can have 2 different phone numbers (PHONE1 - mobile phone, PHONE2 - desk phone) and many different phone numbers in general registered for one customer (it depends on registration type).

I have tried different methods with CASE WHEN but no success.
Do you have any ideas?

Thank you.

In the example below count should be 3.

```
CUSTOMER  PHONE1   PHONE2
abc       123456   123456
abc       123456
abc       654321   777777
abc       654321
```

In this case count should be equal to 3. As:
1st row - phone matches, then it is treated as 1 unique phone number.
2nd row - same as in the first row, still 1 unique phone number.
3rd row - phone1 and phone2 does not match, 2 unique numbers.
4th row - same as in the 3rd row, then in total 3 unique numbers.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LATERAL to unpivot phone numbers

```
WITH tbl(CUSTOMER,  PHONE1,   PHONE2) AS (
     SELECT'abc', '123456', '123456' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
     SELECT'abc', '123456', NULL     FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
     SELECT'abc', '654321', '777777' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
     SELECT'abc', '654321', NULL     FROM DUAL       
)
SELECT CUSTOMER, COUNT(DISTINCT p) cnt  
FROM tbl 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT PHONE1 p FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT PHONE2 FROM DUAL
  ) t
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(CUSTOMER,  PHONE1,   PHONE2) AS
  (

     SELECT 'abc',       '123456',   '123456' UNION ALL 
     SELECT'abc' ,      '123456',    ' '      UNION ALL 
     SELECT'abc' ,      '654321' ,  '777777'  UNION ALL 
     SELECT'abc' ,      '654321',   ' '        
  )
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PHONE1)FROM 
  (
    SELECT PHONE1 FROM CTE AS C
       UNION ALL 
    SELECT PHONE2 FROM CTE AS C2
 )X WHERE X.PHONE1<>' '
```

I guess, you can try something like above query. I replaced non-existing phones with empty string (' '), may be in your case it is NULL-value then you need to replace `X.PHONE1<>' '` with `X.PHONE1 IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Hi, thanks but I have a phone table which consists of millions rows, then wondering if I can really use UNION ALL in the first brackets?

Comment: In my opinion in this case the problem is not about UNION ALL, but about performance of COUNT DISTINCT

Comment: This is missing `FROM DUAL` in all of the `SELECT` statements in the CTE.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
    COUNT(DISTINCT(phones)) 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        phone  AS phones 
    FROM
        customers 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        phone2 AS phones
    FROM
        customers
);
```